# Display field section based on product attribute term

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce plugin for checkout fields manager. I've created two field section which I will use them based on product attributer term is on customer's shopping cart.

The code below does not work properly for this case: If customer choose (add to cart) "Children" product attribute term, the show field section on checkout page or if he/she choose "Adult" product attribute term then hide "Children" field section and show other section for "Adult".

To add a filter to control the display of the custom section, I wrote:

```
function custom_show_children_section($show, $section_name) {
if ($section_name === 'children_selection_data') {
    if (cart_contains_children_product()) {
        $show = true;
    } else {
        $show = false;
    }
}
return $show;
}
```

Function to check if the cart contains a product with the 'children' attribute term, I wrote:

```
function cart_contains_children_product() {
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
    // Check if the product has the 'children' attribute term
    if (has_children_attribute_term($cart_item['product_id'])) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false; }
```

Function to check if a product has the 'children' attribute term, I wrote:

```
function has_children_attribute_term($product_id) {
$term_slug = 'children'; // Replace with the actual slug of the attribute term
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Check if the product has the specified attribute term
if ($product && has_term($term_slug, 'pa_registration-for', $product_id)) {
    return true;
}else

return false; }
```

So, the problem is, whether customer adds "Adult" the "Children" field section does not hide.

How to fix this??

Comment: well first off that else in has_children_attribute_term doesn't really make sense. Could you explain some of the helper functions more?

Comment: nm just share more information and I will try and help.

Comment: As you are using a 3rd party plugin for checkout fields, and you are not able to provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce your issue, so nobody can't really help you actually, or guess things by magic. Inside your last function, remove everything and just use: `return has_term('children', 'pa_registration-for', $product_id);`. Why? Because `$product = wc_get_product($product_id);` is not used and `has_term()` is a conditional function that outputs a boolean value.

Comment: Hello @amac, I am using this plug: https://www.themehigh.com/docs/conditional-rules-for-woocommerce-checkout-fields-display-rules/

custom_show_children_section($show, $section_name): This function is hooked to the thwcfe_show_section filter. It checks whether the provided $section_name matches the target section ("children_selection_data"). If it does, it determines whether to show or hide the section based on the presence of products with the desired attribute term.

Comment: @amac continue to my previous comment to you: 

has_children_attribute_term($product_id): This function checks whether a product with a given $product_id has the desired attribute term ("children"). It retrieves the product object using wc_get_product($product_id) and checks if the product is associated with the specified attribute term using the has_term() function. If the term is found, it returns true, indicating that the product has the attribute term.

Comment: @amac - cart_contains_children_product(): This function iterates through the items in the WooCommerce cart and checks if any of the cart items have the attribute term "children." If at least one item with the attribute term is found, it returns true, indicating that the section should be shown. Otherwise, it returns false.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please check my comments to amac. I am using this 3rd party plugin: https://www.themehigh.com/product/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor-pro/

Comment: I know that you are using a 3rd party plugin, as you mention that in your question. But as said on my first comment *"As you are using a 3rd party plugin for checkout fields, and you are not able to provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce your issue, so nobody can't really help you actually, or guess things by magic."*… So you should ask in Themehigh support pages instead.

Comment: @SteveK., To me what you are describing is just the simple fact that your fields don't match 'children' but they match 'Adult'. Are you debugging this? If so var_dump($product). If the issue you are having is what I described in the first sentence, make the function has_children_attribute_term more flexible and add a second parameter of string|array $slugTerm. also pass the product in instead of relooking it up. Also I will add an answer with more explaination, but you shouldn't need all this extra stuff. idk your experience, php or wordpress developer, so I don't want to over complicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly looking at some websites, I came across this example that may or may not be helpful. I at least think it can help simplify some of the functions and potentially ease some of the debugging.

```
// $cart conditionals (if)
WC()->cart->is_empty()
WC()->cart->needs_payment()
WC()->cart->show_shipping()
WC()->cart->needs_shipping()
WC()->cart->needs_shipping_address()
WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax()
 
// Get $cart totals
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
WC()->cart->subtotal;
WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal();
WC()->cart->get_taxes_total();
WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();
WC()->cart->get_coupons();
WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( 'coupon_code' );
WC()->cart->get_fees();
WC()->cart->get_discount_total();
WC()->cart->get_total( 'edit' );
WC()->cart->total;
WC()->cart->get_tax_totals();
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
WC()->cart->get_fee_tax();
WC()->cart->get_discount_tax();
WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();
WC()->cart->get_shipping_taxes();
  
// Loop over $cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
   $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
   $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
   $price = WC()->cart->get_product_price( $product );
   $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $product, $cart_item['quantity'] );
   $link = $product->get_permalink( $cart_item );
   // Anything related to $product, check $product tutorial
   $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
   $whatever_attribute = $product->get_attribute( 'whatever' );
   $whatever_attribute_tax = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_whatever' );
   $any_attribute = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_whatever'];
   $meta = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
}
 
// Get $cart customer billing / shipping
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_first_name();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_last_name();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_company();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_email();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_phone();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_country();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_state();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_postcode();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_city();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_address();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_billing_address_2();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_first_name();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_last_name();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_company();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_country();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_state();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_postcode();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_city();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_address();
WC()->cart->get_customer()->get_shipping_address_2();
 
// Other stuff
WC()->cart->get_cross_sells();
WC()->cart->get_cart_item_tax_classes_for_shipping();
WC()->cart->get_cart_hash();
WC()->cart->get_customer();
```

not sure which but I think you can basically minimalize your functions by using these. Then perhaps var_dump the results may lead us to your issue. Which currently I think you are looking for a slug of 'children' but want 'Adult' to also be included in that check.

```
   $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
   $whatever_attribute = $product->get_attribute( 'whatever' );
   $whatever_attribute_tax = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_whatever' );
   $any_attribute = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_whatever'];
   $meta = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
```

If this doesn't resolve or lead you to a happy path please comment and I will edit/update my answer accordingly.

I also found this in the documentation that you sent.

Case 4: Conditionally display checkout fields
There are already too many inbuilt conditions available in the WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor plugin.

But if you have some amazing conditions that are not covered by our plugin, here is a simple code snippet for you to display or hide checkout fields based on your conditions.

Use the below code snippet in your theme’s or child theme’s functions.php file. Update the string {field_name} in the filter tag in the code snippet with your field name.

https://www.themehigh.com/docs/display-rules-use-cases-and-more-examples/

```
function thwcfe_show_field_condition($show){

// Your conditions here
// $show Variable have the value True or False as per the field settings in your backend
// Return True to display the field
// Return False to hide the field

}

add_filter('thwcfe_show_field_{field_name}', 'thwcfe_show_field_condition');
```

Comment: I wanted to share some great news with you – I've successfully found a solution to the challenge I was facing, and everything is now working smoothly! Your assistance and the information you provided were incredibly valuable in guiding me towards the right direction. 
Thanks once again for your time and input!

Comment: Awesome glad to have helped @SteveK.